# Reuse code from class to class

Tags: c#, winforms, namespaces, code-reuse

I have 2 `winforms` called `AppNamespace.MYForm` and `AnotherNamespace.AnotherForm`.
  They both have a button.

When the user click on the button of `AnotherNamespace.AnotherForm` I would like to perform a click on the button located on `AppNamespace.MYForm`.

However, there is a constriant that `AnotherNamespace` cannot use `AppNamespace`.
This prevents me from doing   :

```
AppNamespace.MYForm firstForm = new AppNamespace.MYForm();
firstForm.button.PerformClick();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you don't try to register the second button event an rise it when the first one clicked

Comment: @MoezRebai, The same code is about to be performed on two different events. Anyway, Can you please post some code how to do so, so that I couls understand if this solves the issue? Thanks

Comment: how `AnotherForm` know `MyForm` exists? and get the reference? do `AppNamespace` can use `AnotherNamespace`?

Comment: @Alex, `AnotherForm` does not have a reference to the form from the second namespace. The `Appnamespcase` knows `AnotherNamespace`. Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve your problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually executing event of any control is a bad practice. Create separate method and execute it instead.

You can create interface then implement it to both forms. The interface should contains a method `PerformClick`.

```
public Interface IMyInterface
{
    void PerformClick(string _module);
}

public class Form1 : IMyInterface
{
   public void IMyInterface.PerformClick(string _module) 
   {
      //CODE HERE
      if (Application.OpenForms["Form2"] != null && _module != "Form2")
          ((IMyInterface)Application.OpenForms["Form2"]).PerformClick(_module);
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.PerformClick(this.Name);
   }
}


public class Form2 : IMyInterface
{
   public void IMyInterface.PerformClick() 
   {
      //CODE HERE
      if (Application.OpenForms["Form1"] != null && _module != "Form1")
          ((IMyInterface)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]).PerformClick(_module);
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.PerformClick(this.Name);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the button click code in a helper class/another namespace and call it in button click.

You can use the method in any namespace by calling helper namespace and method.

Answer (score 0):

Either make the `Button` on the second form `public` by editing the Form2.Designer.cs:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

And register its `Click` with the 1st Form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // or whatever you do to create the 2nd form..
    AnotherNamespace.Form2 F2 = new AnotherNamespace.Form2();
    F2.Show();
    // register the click:
    F2.button1.Click += button2_Click;
}
```

Or create a `Property` in the 2nd form:

```
public Button myButton { get; set;  }
```

And set it to the `Button`:

```
public Form2()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   myButton = button1;
}
```

Now you can register its `Click` like this:

```
F2.myButton.Click += button2_Click;
```